# Help with simple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'd like to know why this is wrong:

\begin{align}
\int \operatorname{sen}(x)·\cos(x) \,dx &\underset{\uparrow}{=}\int u\ du=\frac{u^2}{2}+c=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{sen}^2(x)+c\\&\boxed{CV\\\phantom{d}u=\operatorname{sen}(x)\\du=\cos(x)\,dx}
\end{align}

When checking on WolframAlpha its done this other way:

\begin{align}
\int \operatorname{sen}(x)·\cos(x) \,dx&\underset{\uparrow}{=}-\int u\ du=-\frac{u^2}{2}+c=-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x)+c\\&\boxed{CV\\\phantom{d}u=\cos(x)\\du=-\operatorname{sen}(x)\,dx}
\end{align}

Wouldn't both ways of solving it be correct?

Comment: Both are correct ! don't forget that $sin^2a+cos^2a=1$ !

Comment: Observe that $\sin^2(x) = - \cos^2(x) +c$.

Comment: @Nikunj $sen$ is spanish notation for $sin$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Woah, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, the [Pythagorean Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity) states that $$\operatorname{sen}^{2}(x) + \cos^{2}(x) = 1.$$  This means that $$\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{sen}^{2}(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(x) + 1,$$ and so for a constant $c$ we have $$\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{sen}^{2}(x) + c = -\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(x) + 1 + c.$$  Writing $C = 1 + c$, we can write $$\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{sen}^{2}(x) + c = -\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(x) + C.$$  This tells us that the two integration constants are different, but since the integration constant is arbitrary it doesn't matter which form of the antiderivative we take.  Both are correct.